# SQL Insert statement with multi-part identifier could not be bound error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute an insert statement.  If the record already exists in the table, I do not want the record inserted.  This is the code I am using.  I keep getting the following error and I am unable to determine why....

> The multi-part identifier
>   "TLSQL.DBTL.dbo.Table_Sch_Lead.Sch_FSList_Student_ID" could not be
>   bound.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO CRM.dbo.CHStlsqlLead 
    (tlld_FSList_StudentID,
    tlld_Updated_By,
    tlld_Updated_Date,
    tlld_schLeadID,
    tlld_SchLeadGUID,
    tlld_LeadStatus,
    tlld_SchLeadRecdDate)
    SELECT  Sch_FSList_Student_ID,
            Updated_By, 
            Updated_Date,
            Sch_Lead_ID,
            Sch_Lead_GUID, 
            Sch_Lead_Status, 
            Sch_Lead_Received_Date 
    FROM TLSQL.DBTL.dbo.Table_Sch_Lead
    WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CHStlsqlLead
    WHERE CRM.dbo.CHStlsqlLead.tlld_FSList_StudentID = TLSQL.DBTL.dbo.Table_Sch_Lead.Sch_FSList_Student_ID);
```

Comment: Use alias names for tables and use those aliases in the column names for particular tables

Comment: Can you use alias names in an insert statement?

Comment: Not in insert statement. Use in select statement

Answer (score 1):

Try with Table alias

```
    SELECT  Sch_FSList_Student_ID,
            Updated_By,
            Updated_Date,
            Sch_Lead_ID,
            Sch_Lead_GUID,
            Sch_Lead_Status,
            Sch_Lead_Received_Date
    FROM    TLSQL.DBTL.dbo.Table_Sch_Lead schl
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                         FROM   CRM.dbo.CHStlsqlLead chl
                         WHERE  chl.tlld_FSList_StudentID = schl.Sch_FSList_Student_ID ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a '5 dot' name addressing mechanism in SqlServer. Use an alias on the table name and reference columns relative to the alias:

```
 FROM TLSQL.DBTL.dbo.Table_Sch_Lead x
    WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CHStlsqlLead
    WHERE CRM.dbo.CHStlsqlLead.tlld_FSList_StudentID = x.Sch_FSList_Student_ID);
```